# Add new field to paragraph when link is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, html, field, dynamic

I have a form where I would like to add new fields for file uploading when the user clicks a link.

So I have made a paragraph with id:

```
<p id="proof">default field is here and want more</p>
```

Then on my jQuery I have:

```
$('#newField').click(
    function(){
        $('#proof').append('<label for="file">Arquivo:</label><input type="file" name="arquivo[]" id="file" /><br />\n<label>Descrição:</label><input type="text" name="descricao[]" class="text small" /><br />');
        return false;
    }
);
```

And here I have the link that should be clicked to add new fields:

```
<a href="#" id="#newField">Mais provas</a>
```

I am quite new to jQuery and not sure if I could add it to a paragraph or if I am tied to a div and if it should work for a paragraph what have I done wrong here ?

**It is not adding new fields as I was hoping it would, in fact it doesnt add nothing when u click the link.**

Comment: "what have I done wrong here" --- this doesn't explain us what issues you have experienced.

Comment: @zerkms it is not adding new fields as I was hoping it would, in fact it doesnt add nothing when u click the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

`<a href="#" id="newField">Mais provas</a>`

instead of

`<a href="#" id="#newField">Mais provas</a>`

You have added an extra `#` in id of link.

Comment: omg so true that I missed that out ... thanks a lot for spotting it... rrr have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer.